# Get file path in minifilter driver

Tags: c, winapi, driver, wdk, minifilter

I've used the code below but it is giving me an result of file path.

```
status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data,
        FLT_FILE_NAME_OPENED |
        FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_ALWAYS_ALLOW_CACHE_LOOKUP,
        &nameInfo);
    DbgPrint("\n Filename : %wZ",&nameInfo->Name);
```

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Users\filename.ext
```

But I want the file path as I

```
c:\Users\Filename.ext
```

How can I get this please help.

Comment: Probably a better way but FltParseFileNameInformation() to get the volume path, then a lookup from a list of the results of a call to  querydosdevice() for each getlogicaldrivestrings() - remembering the path may not have a corresponding physical drive letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NameLength = (USHORT)dosName.MaximumLength + Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName.MaximumLength + 2;  
NameBuffer = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(PagedPool,NameLength,NC_MAPPING_TAG);
NameString.Length = 0;
NameString.MaximumLength = NameLength;
NameString.Buffer = NameBuffer;
RtlCopyUnicodeString(&NameString, &dosName);
RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString(&NameString, &Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution, but its again not using Drive letter.But using Volume GUID

more :
https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2014-issue2/drive-letter-alternatives/

Comment: Its for kmdf and umdf drivers I want same thing for Minifilter driver can you please help.

Comment: FltGetVolumeGuidName - function that been used is part of minifilter. Source:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx